# If condition here is only working If(DES!=0) ,in any other case it isnt getting pass to next condition ie elif while using it in UDF (PYSPARK)

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark

df_Description4 = df_Description3.na.fill("0", subset=["DES", "INV", "MKT", "SHO"]).distinct()

def Merge(a,b,c,d):
if ("DES" != "0"):
return a
elif ("INV" != "0"):
return b
elif ("MKT" != "0"):
return c
elif ("SHO" != "0"):
return d
else:
return ''

myudf = F.udf(Merge,StringType())

df_Description5=df_Description4.withColumn("Descriptions",myudf(df_Description4.DES, df_Description4.INV, df_Description4.MKT,df_Description4.SHO)).drop("DescriptionVALUE", "DES", "INV", "MKT","SHO").distinct()

REAL OUTPUT
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7peb2.png

TARGET OUTPUT
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tG9Fx.png

Comment: because `"DES"` is a string which is always neq `"0"`

Comment: yes i have figured this, but what should be the solution here.?

Comment: how do "DES", "INV", "MKT", "SHO" columns look like?

Comment: datatype of these columns are string. "Descpriton" is created from these columns which contains the data of these columns like in "DES" if there is a value then "Description" column will store that value, however if "DES" has "0" in the particular row then it should had to print empty string but it only showing 0.

Comment: you can try using [`when().otherwise()`](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-when-otherwise/) (which is the API equivalent of [SQL's `CASE WHEN`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp)) --

Comment: i think it only for few columns with same value in other columns in my dataframe there are almost 1200 entries and each row data contain different value. So how could i use when function over here. Pls can u suggest me syntax using when().